# Changing variable value in module with async function and than importing in other one

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, commonjs

I have a problem with reading the variable from a file, which changes it with the promise function.

I have two modules:

- one that exposes configuration, and obtains mac address from the device, the app is running on
- one that consumes the configuration

**Example**

config.js

```
// some imports

let currentMacAddress;
(async () => {
    currentMacAddress = await toMAC(cameraIp);
    console.log(currentMacAddress) // works, sets mac address as expected
})();

module.exports = {
    currentMacAddress,
}
```

somefile.js

```
const { currentMacAddress } = require('./config.js')

console.log(currentMacAddress) // undefined

setTimeout(() => console.log(currentMacAddress), 10000) // undefined, the timeout is enough for this operation
```

I believe this is because `require` does import only one time, so it sets the variable with the value of `currentMacAddress` which is `undefined` and that's it.

How can I persist the value in `currentMacAddress` so that any other module could access its updated value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the `currentMacAddress` a property of the exported object:

```js
const config = {currentMacAddress: undefined};
(async () => {
  config.currentMacAddress = await toMAC(cameraIp);
})();
module.exports = config;
```

And import it without deconstructing:

```js
const config = require('./config.js')
console.log(config.currentMacAddress)
setTimeout(() => console.log(config.currentMacAddress), 10000)
```

Comment: Notice this doesn't help as long as the importing statement destructures the object (`const { currentMacAddress } = require('./config.js')`)

Comment: No need to create a new object btw, just do `module.exports.currentMacAddress = …`

Answer (score 0):

Export the async function from `config.js`

`config.js`

```
const some = async () => {
  await timeout(3000);
  currentMacAddress = "some value";
  return currentMacAddress;
};

function timeout(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

module.exports = some;
```

Now in other file

```
somefile.js
```

import like this

```
const some = require("./config.js");

const start = async () => {
  const currentMacAddress = await some();
  console.log(currentMacAddress);
};
start();
```